# Link does not correspond with time in google calendar

Tags: php, html, calendar

I am using a link to google calendar on my homepage to make it possible for people to add the event to their calendar. I generate the link in the following way:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=<?php echo $p->name?>&dates=<?php echo date('Ymd\\THi00\\Z', strtotime($p->start))?>/<?php echo date('Ymd\\THi00\\Z', strtotime($ps->end))?>&details=<?php echo $p->l?>&location=<?php echo $c->name?>&trp=false&sprop=&sprop=name:"target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="/images/google_calendar_icon"></a>
```

This outputs e.g. the following link when clicking the icon

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=Vuelta+a+Espa%C3%B1a&dates=20140902T160000Z/20140902T174500Z&details=10.+etape:+Real+Monasterio+de+Santa+Mar%C3%ADa+de+Veruela-Borja,+36,7+km+-+enkeltstart.&location&trp=false&sprop&sprop=name:&sf=true&output=xml
```

This is all good - the only problem is that as you can see the link suggests that the starttime is 20140902T1600 which is perfect and indicates the start time to be at 16:00 (4PM) but in the google calendar event with this link the time being filled in as the start time is 18:00 (6pm). Does anyone have any idea why this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the datetime is taken as GMT and it is rendered taking into account the user's timezone.

Comment: Yes - I have realized that much, but given that I am in the same timezone as when I created it, then there should not be any difference, should there?

Comment: You mean that the in the settings of the Google account you are using the tome zone is `GMT+0` ?

Comment: I am using GMT+1 which corresponds with the timezone I am in and that the server is in.

Comment: And what about DST? + the server time does not have anything to have with it.

Comment: No, this should not be the problem either. A solution would be to just subtract two hours from the time that I send them in the link - how would you go about doing this?